# Transparent profile-picture

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-picture

I have changed my profile picture many days ago. This is what happened (I'm accessing Stack Exchange through Chrome on Windows):

1. My profile picture on the top of the screen is changed.

   [image: Profile picture showing in topbar]
2. My profile picture on the main screen is 'transparent', and on Stack Overflow it is black:

   [image: Stack Overflow usercard with profile picture not showing up]

   On meta.SE it is blue:

   [image: Meta.SE usercard with profile picture not showing up]

Is this a bug? Or is something wrong with my computer?

Comment: It looks like it's just caching on your end. I see your avatar here.

Comment: How long will this typically last for? It has been like this for a long time already.

Comment: Try deleting the cache of the browser. The easiest option is Ctrl+F5 that will do hard refresh of the page and re-download the resources.

Comment: I have tried. Now even the pfp in the top bar is blank. @VLAZ

Comment: *How long will this typically last for?* Normally things take [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/158100) here ... also relevant on the same theme [caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221414/158100) ... also I might be on [Iceland](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/54746/158100) ...

Comment: I don't really get the joke, but I understand what you mean.

Comment: It's not transparent, it's missing.

Comment: That's pretty wierd. I'm really confused now. It's still related to caching, right?

Comment: I can see your avatar at the sites you mention.

Comment: That image is on the server alright. Does singapore suffer from the great wall of internet as well? Perhaps you are not allowed to visit imgur.com and hence can't load the image, but it was in your cache from uploading before.

Comment: @Luuklag possibly, see [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/singapore/comments/xznp1/is_anyone_elses_imgur_blocked/), but for me, my parents used chrome to only whitelist certain websites. I think that's not the problem though, it loaded for a bit before.

Comment: Unless `*.imgur.com` is whitelisted you won't be able to see it

Comment: @fez.tival-QnPolice probably before changing you had the default avatar which is hosted under gravatar.com that's the reason you originally saw it, and after changing to manually uploaded image you don't see it as it's hosted on imgur.com and it's blocked by your parents.